# Topology on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Consider the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers,with the topology $\tau$ in which every set is closed if and only if it is empty or $\mathbb{Z}$ or finite. Then which of the following statements are true?

1. $\tau$ is a subspace topology induced by the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.
2. $\mathbb{Z}$ is compact in the topology $\tau$.
3. $\mathbb{Z}$ is Hausdorff in the topology $\tau$
4. Every infinite subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ is dence in the topology $\tau$.

I don't have any idea.

Comment: This topology is called the _cofinite topology_. For 1. figure out which subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ are open (or equivalently, which are closed) with respect to the subspace topology and compare this with the cofinite topology. Points 2. and 3. should be easy if you understand how open sets look like in the cofinite topology. For 4. you should be able to compute the closure of an infinite set.

Comment: For future reference, please provide additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I had already written I have no idea

Comment: "Having no idea" might be the reason why you do not provide sufficient context, but "you do not provide sufficient context" is the reason why this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1: It is obvious that the subspace topology of $\mathbb{Z}$ induced by the "usual" one of $\mathbb{R}$ is discret.

For 2: A set $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ is open in $(\mathbb{Z}, \tau)$ if its compliment is finite. Thus if you have an open cover $\mathcal{C}$ take any $C \in \mathcal{C}$. Since $C$ is open it covers all of $\mathbb{Z}$ except some finite number of points, say $x_1, \dots, x_n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Take $C_i \in \mathcal{C}$ wich $x_i \in C_i$. (this is of course true for *any* topological space with cofinite topology, nothing special about $\mathbb{Z}$ here)

For 3: Let $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $\tau$ is Hausdorff. Then you would have $U,V$ open sets seperating $x$ from $y$. In particular $U \cap V = \emptyset$. Hence, by de Morgan, $U^c \cup V^c = \mathbb{Z}$. But the complements $U^c$ and $V^c$ are finite, by definition. Thus a condtradiction. (we only used that $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite, so this is true for any infinite set with this particular topology)

For 4: By definition closures are *closed* sets. Moreover $A \subseteq \bar{A}$, $\bar{A}$ is the closure of $A$. But in $\tau$ closed sets are either finite or the whole space. So if $A$ is infinite, only $\bar{A} = \mathbb{Z}$ is possible. (again nothing but infiniteness of $\mathbb{Z}$ has been used).

Comment: "Since $C$ is open it covers all of $\mathbb{Z}$ except some finite number of points" why?  Is this is due to cofinite topology? As I know, definition of open set 'does not' tell this!

Comment: Yes. By definition a set $C$ in the cofinite topology is open iff its complement is finite. Look e.g. the corresponding wiki article.

Comment: sir, thanks for replying :-)